# Using OWL.js in ASP.net repeater

Tags: asp.net, repeater, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I am trying to use the Owl Carousel library (https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/) with ASP.net repeater.  I have found that adding items, via the repeater, causes the HTML/CSS to not be rendered correctly.  Here is my owl/repeater code:

```
    <div class="owl-carousel add-owl">
       <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
             <ContentTemplate>
                  <asp:Repeater ID="rptr_stories" runat="server">    
                        <ItemTemplate>
                             <div class="item" style="padding:10px; float:left;">

                                  <p class="testimonial-detail">
                                      Just a few short sentences to describe the content of this blog
                                  </p>
                                   <div class="test-name">
                                       <strong>Some Name</strong> <br>
                                       title One
                                   </div>                             
                              </div>
                         </ItemTemplate>    
                  </asp:Repeater>
              </ContentTemplate>
       </asp:UpdatePanel>
  </div> <!-- /.owl-carousel -->
```

This causes the html/css to not render correctly causing the items to stack on top of each other, instead of align horizontally.

If it would be helpful to view the outputted HTML, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just did this without the repeater.  I just made sure the data source was declared public, in my codebehind.  Then, in my ASPX page, just did a foreach loop:

```
 <%  For Each blog As Blog In BlogStories  %> <!-- loop through the list -->
     <div class="item" style="padding:10px; float:left;">
         <p class="testimonial-detail">
              Just a few short sentences to describe the content of this blog
        </p>
        <div class="test-name">
             <strong>Some Name</strong> <br>
                 title One
        </div>                             
    </div>    
 <% Next%> <!--End the for loop -->
```